# PHPMailer returning False even when mail is sent sucessfully

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have created a PHP script to send emails from my website to my support email address. The script is using PHPMailer but it seems to have a bug when sending a email as its returning false like it was unable to send the email but is sending it with no problems, here is my PHP code...

```
<?php

    header('application/json');
    require_once('phpmailer.php');

    // Retreive all the required fields
    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
    $message = $_REQUEST['message'];
    $timestamp = date("dmYhms", mktime(date(h), date(m), date(s), date(m), date(d), date(y)));

    // Get users ip address
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARD_FOR'] != '') {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARD_FOR'];
    } else {
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

    // Check a name was specified
    if ($name == ''){
        $output = json_encode(array('status'=>'invalid','message'=>'Please enter your full name.'));
        die($output);
    }

    // Check a email address was specified
    if ($email == ''){
        $output = json_encode(array('status'=>'invalid','message'=>'Please enter your email address.'));
        die($output);
    }

    // Check a subject was specified
    if ($subject == ''){
        $output = json_encode(array('status'=>'invalid','message'=>'Please enter a subject for your message.'));
        die($output);
    }

    // Check a message was specified
    if ($message == ''){
        $output = json_encode(array('status'=>'invalid','message'=>'A message without a message, interesting...'));
        die($output);
    }

    // Double check all the fields are not blank and prepare the message
    if ($name != '' && $email != '' && $subject != '' && $message != ''){

        // Check the email address specified is valid
        if (preg_match("/^(\w+((-\w+)|(\w.\w+))*)\@(\w+((\.|-)\w+)*\.\w+$)/", $email)){

            $mail = new phpmailer;
            $mail->From = $email;
            $mail->FromName = $name;
            $mail->AddAddress("support@idify.me", "IDify Ltd");
            $mail->AddReplyTo("support@idify.me", "IDify Ltd");
            $mail->WordWrap = 500;
            $mail->IsHTML(true);
            $mail->Subject = $subject;
            $mail->Body = "<strong>Ip Address:&nbsp;</strong>".$ipaddress."<br/><strong>Timestamp:&nbsp;</strong>".$timestamp."<br/><strong>Fullname:&nbsp;</strong>".$name."<br/><strong>Email Address:&nbsp;</strong>".$email."<br/><strong>Subject:&nbsp;</strong>".$subject."<br/><p>".$message."</p>";

            if($mail->Send()){
                $output = json_encode(array('status'=>'valid','message'=>'Your message is on its way, we will be in touch with you soon.'));
                die($output);
            } else {
                $output = json_encode(array('status'=>'invalid','message'=>'We were unable to send your message, please try again later.'));
                die($output);
            }

        }else{

            $output = json_encode(array('status'=>'invalid','message'=>'Please enter a valid email address.'));
            die($output);

        }

    }

?>
```

Thanks for any help given, its very strange but I'm sure we can work it out.

Answer (score 2):

Just a note about the code before I take a stab at the problem, I would not bother verifying the email with a regular expression. While there is an RFC standard for doing so many mail servers have different implementations and I have found that simply trying to send the email is better than bouncing out potentially valid email addresses.

And as far as it returning False do you mean that `$mail->Send()` returns False?
I took a look at the [PHPMailer source code](http://phpmailer.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/phpmailer/phpmailer/trunk/class.phpmailer.php?revision=452&view=markup):

```
545     public function Send() {
SNIP    SNIP
581       } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
582       $this->SetError($e->getMessage());
583       if ($this->exceptions) {
584       throw $e;
585       }
586       echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
587       return false;
588       }
589     }
```

If the send function is throwing an exception inside the switch statement in line 572 then you could have a case where the mail is sent however you hit the catch block and return False.

If this is the case then there may be an issue with your configuration, would you be willing to try an [example script](http://phpmailer.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/phpmailer/phpmailer/trunk/examples/test_mail_basic.php?revision=452&view=markup) from the project and report the results of that?

Comment: $mail->Send() is returning false but when ask PHPMailer to return if their is any problems, nothing is returned and the message is sent as normal.

Comment: Alright, so there's no exception thrown? Did the test script do the same thing and error out?

Comment: Yes, the example does the same thing

Comment: Then my money is a configuration error. Ask a separate question about that and post the configuration. Maybe someone with sharp eyes will find something wrong. It could be your host as well so make sure to include information about that.